# How to infer values for data structure fields in Python construct?

Tags: python, parsing, construct

Here's a simple tag-length-value structure defined using the `construct` library for Python:

```
Tlv = Struct(
    'tag' / Int16ub,
    'length' / Int32ub,
    'value' / Array(this.length, Byte)
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tlv_data = dict(tag=1, length=5, value=b'\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF')
    encoded = Tlv.build(tlv_data)
    print(encoded)
    decoded = Tlv.parse(encoded)
    print(decoded)
```

While the example correctly encodes and decodes the data, I need to know the length of the `value` field in advance and supply it via the `length` parameter.

Is there an approach that allows me to initialize the structure by passing the bare minimum, i.e., `tlv_data = dict(tag=1, value=b'\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF')` and have it figure out on its own what the adequate value of the `length` field should be?

At the same time, when I parse raw data, I expect it to extract the length from the raw data and then ensure that the `value` is indeed that many bytes long.

Is this supposed to work in principle, or am I misunderstanding the ideology of `construct`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe `Rebuild` is what you are looking for, in this instance.

From the example currently on [Construct's docs](https://construct.readthedocs.io/en/latest/misc.html#rebuild):

```
>>> st = Struct(
...     "count" / Rebuild(Byte, len_(this.items)),
...     "items" / Byte[this.count],
... )
>>> st.build(dict(items=[1,2,3]))
b'\x03\x01\x02\x03'
```